# TYPO3 autoload of external classes

Tags: typo3, autoload, extbase

I like to use autoload in TYPO3 6.0< for external classes e.g. `Symfony\Component\Yaml`.

Is there an easier way to create an autoload than ext_autoload.php? The library I what to use have very much classes to define if using ext_autoload.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK not. This functionality will be available once the package manager API is merged. Then you can just require this as a full package.

Currently, I would include the autoloader of the package (if it has one) into the ext_localconf.php.

You can use `extdevel` to create the `ext_autoload.php` automatically, but I am not sure if it will create it right.

Comment: Thanks Philipp, I used `scandir` but the hint with the included autoloder rocks :) Machmal sieht man den Wald vor lauter Bäumen nicht…